# How can I repair OS X Lion's Keychain Access?

Tags: macos

I can’t open Keychain Access (the system keychain) to modify; it freezes when I try to open it. How can I fix this problem?

Comment: Would you mind posting all the lines of Console.app (it resides in /Applications/Utilities) which have "Keychain Access" into it? Anyway I'd repair the Disk Permission to begin with (Go to /Applications/Utilities/Disk Utility.app, click on your HD, and then click on "Repair Disk Permissions".)

Comment: I can into Keychain Access,and there are "login" ,"PrivateEncrypedDatak" ,"system" inside.And I can't open the "system"

Comment: Are you still having issues after graham's advice to run the usual keychain first aid steps ?

Comment: It appears as if the Op has abandoned this topic, but I am currently struggle with what I think is the same issue. After a reboot, I get an indeterminate amount of time before the Keychain stops working. When I am able to get into it, the First Aid reports no problems. Disk Utility also reports no issues with the drive. The next time it happens, I can post some Console logs here, unless I should open a new question...

Comment: @Kirk You should ask a new question and link to this one. That way, you can accept an answer as correct.

Answer (score 1):

## Keychain Access: Keychain First Aid

As you can open Keychain Access, first use its first aid to verify or repair:

[image: screenshot of the 'Keychain First Aid' menu menu option in Keychain Access]

As commented, it's also good to use Disk Utility to verify or repair *permissions*. Also (not specific to this question) take the opportunity to verify the integrity of your startup volume.